# How to Insert spaces in (cout << ... << args) using fold expressions?

Tags: c++17, fold-expression

Given

```
template<typename ...Types>
void print(Types&& ...args) {
    (cout << ... << args);
}
// ....
print(1, 2, 3, 4); // prints 1234
```

How to add spaces so we get `1 2 3 4`?

**Update:**

Correct answer: 
`((std::cout << args << ' ') , ...);`

Comment: That's not what fold expressions are for.

Comment: OK, here is the formal question: how to add arbitrary new items in the middle of a function parameter pack?

Comment: That's not what function parameter packs are for ;) I'm kidding, but I am being somewhat serious. Parameter packs are very specific tools for very specific jobs, and unpacking them is quite restricted. When they're exactly what you need, they work great, leading to clean and easily understood code. When they're nothing like what you need, you wouldn't use them. But when they're *almost* what you need, they're *annoyingly unusable*.

Comment: You are right, It makes sense. The definition is "A function parameter pack is a function parameter that accepts zero or more function arguments." We can not add something in the middle of function arguments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The usual workaround is to fold over the comma operator instead, though the simplistic approach will leave a trailing space:

```
((std::cout << args << ' '), ...);
```

Changing it to avoid the trailing space is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: ```a.cpp:11:24: error: binary expression in operand of fold-expression
     (std::cout << args << ' ', ...);```

I get this

Comment: You need an extra pair of parentheses, `((std::cout << args << ' ') , ...)`